# Software to run a local python script on a server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I regularly have Python scripts that take up to 8+ hours to complete that I want to run on a remote server. However, I don't want to go through the hassle of setting up a server, setting an environment, running the script and shutting down the server after the script is done every time.

Ideally, I'm looking for a CLI product like Heroku that spins up a server, runs the script in an environment and shuts down the server after the script is done.

AWS Lambda functions sound close to what I'm looking for, but they have a runtime limit. Are there other solutions that would fit these criteria?

Thanks!

Comment: For something that runs that long, ECS tasks on Fargate are probably the closest you can get right now, but there will be some setup involved.

Comment: you could wrap it all up in a docker image and then run that docker image as task on ECS . You can trigger the task and once it completes it wills top running. You can run it on Fargate to save having to do any cluster setup and just pay as it runs

Comment: I use ECS (specifically Fargate) for a long running Python job. It takes ~1 hour to complete and i schedule it in off hours so it run every day. It's entirely possible to use a high level approach like CDK and Docker to deploy a Python app, which you can then schedule using something like CW based on an event rule to run every few hours or whenever you need it to.

Comment: A somewhat shameless plug, but if you *are* logging messages in an ECS task and you want to be notified on teams or via email if something fails, I came up with a lib [aws-teams-logger](https://github.com/rnag/aws-teams-logger) so that basically any warning logs or failures are sent as a notification for better visibility purposes.

Comment: oh, and before I forget, here's a sample [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/rnag/4e845ea85c79493978944998bdb1aa4f) I use in my shell script for deployment to ECS, in case anyone is curious.

Comment: It's not that hard to have an Amazon EC2 instance run a script on startup and then turn itself off when the script is finished. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)